# Calculating the average median of a large array (up to 100,000 elements)

Tags: java

I have a large array that I need to calculate the average median with. I have to use recursion, no loops, and no dot operations except for .length.

The array has to be broken up to 3 pieces at most, and the way to break it up is:

- Remainder of 0: Each piece should be [n/3] elements.
- Remainder of 1: First and last piece should be [n/3] elements rounded
  down, the middle should be [n/3] elements rounded up
- Remainder of 2: First and last piece should be [n/3] elements rounded
  up, the middle should be [n/3] elements rounded down

I'm getting stumped with how the recursion is supposed to work once the array surpasses the smaller values. This is what I have thus far,

```
public static double medianAverage(double a, double b, double c) {

     if ((a < b && b < c) || (c < b && b < a)) 
         return b; 

     else if ((b < a && a < c) || (c < a && a < b)) 
         return a; 

     else if(a == c) return b;
     else if(b == c) return a;
     else if(a == b) return c;

     else
         return c;

 }

 /**
  * @return Returns median average
  */
 public static double medianHelper(int[] a, int range, int start, int end) {
     double avg = 0;
     int n = range / 3;


     // Base Cases:
     if(range == 1) return a[start];
     if(range == 2) return (a[start] + a[start + 1]) / 2.0;
     if(range == 3) return medianAverage(a[start], a[start + 1], a[start + 2]);

     if(range > 3) {
         if(range % 3 == 0) {
             double p1 = medianHelper(a, n, start, n);
             double p2 = medianHelper(a, n, n, n * 2);
             double p3 = medianHelper(a, n, n * 2, n * 3);

             return medianAverage(p1, p2, p3);
         }

         if(range % 3 == 1) {
             // TODO: Implement

         }

         if(range % 3 == 2) {
             // TODO: Implement
         }

     }

     return avg;
 }

 public static double median3(int[] a) {
     return medianHelper(a, a.length, 0, a.length);

 }
```

Any help at all is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Average or median? Those are two things. see https://www.dictionary.com/e/mean-median-mode/

Comment: @leonardkraemer Unless the point is to find the median of the 3 pieces, and then return the average of those three medians.

Comment: @KevinO are you sure? I do not see any averaging there. Only medians. To me it looks like finding the median without sorting, divide-and-conquer style.

Comment: @leonardkraemer, no, not sure at all. Just adding a hypothesis. But the fact things are supposed to be broken into three pieces might imply each is supposed to have its median calculated, and if one did that and then averaged the medians, it would fit the title. It is also possible the title is bad.

Comment: @KevinO This kind of uncertainty is exactly why I posted my comment.

Comment: @leonardkraemer It’s an assignment for my class, my professor came up with this averaging of the median, I assume to make the problem more challenging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remainder of 0 means `range = 3n`. According to the rules, you can divide the array into `[0, n]`, `[n + 1, 2n]` and `[2n + 1, 3n]`. Each piece has the size `n` in this case.
- Remainder of 1 means `range = 3n + 1`. According to the rules, you can divide the array into `[0, n]`, `[n + 1, 2n + 1]` and `[2n + 2, 3n + 1]`. The size of first and last piece is `n` and size of the middle piece is `n + 1`.
- Remainder of 2 means `range = 3n + 2`. According to the rules, you can divide the array into `[0, n + 1]`, `[n + 2, 2n + 1]` and `[2n + 2, 3n + 2]`. The size of first and last piece is `n + 1` and the size of the middle piece is `n`.

Once you divide the array into 3 pieces like this, you can recursively try to find medians of each piece. I'm confused what you want to do with the medians, but I'll let you figure it out.